# Huge delay when dismissing and presenting a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have an application that has a `UICollectionView`.  When a user taps on a button on a cell (not the cell itself) as custom popup `UIViewController` appear with a list of options presented in a `UITableView`.  When a user taps one of the options(rows), the current custom pop up `UIViewController` is dismissed and a new `UIViewController` is presented.  I do this using delegate/protocols.

My problem is the following.  When I tap on one of my options, there is a very long delay 1-4 seconds before it is dimissed and another `UIViewController` presented.  At other times it is instant, with no delays.  I have found the following error message in the console when there have been delays.  Can anyone advise?  I am currently getting this issue with row of indexPath[0,2] - please see below.

Error message:

> myApplicationName[7141:3954956] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

My `UITableView` code for tapping on a row:

```
class MoreOptionsOnPDFViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    ....

    var moveDocDelegate: MoveFolder!

    // TAP ON ROW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath == [0,0]{ // EDIT FILE NAME
            print("EDIT FILENAME")

        } else if indexPath == [0,1]{ // EDIT TAGS

            print("EDIT DOCUMENT")

        }else if indexPath == [0,2]{ // MOVE FOLDER

            guard let scanID = self.scanID else{return}
            if let scanID = self.scanID{
                // SHOW MOVE DOCUMENT UIVIEWCONTROLLER
                dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.moveDocDelegate.moveDocument(scanId: scanID)
                }
            }

        } else if indexPath == [0,3]{ // SHARE DOCUMENT
            print("SHARE DOCUMENT")

            if let pdfURL = self.pdfURL{
                self.sharePDF(pdfURL: pdfURL)
            }

        } else if indexPath == [0,4]{ // BIN

        }
    }
}
```

Other Class:

```
 class CollectionViewFolder: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MoreInfoDocument, MoveFolder{

    // SHOW MOVE FOLDER OPTIONS
    func moveDocument(scanId: String) {

        let moveFolderVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "movefolder") as! MoveFolderViewController

        moveFolderVC.scanId = scanId
        present(moveFolderVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/12349) since iOS 8. There is a workaround:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    present(...) or dismiss(...)
}
```

Comment: This is quite strange. And I do not expect from Apple to have a bug like this. Furthermore we have iOS 11.

Comment: @subdan - I was getting killed.  Thank you!

Comment: @Sh_Khan - in this instance. it has so far resolved my issue...no more stalling or extreme latency...so far.

Comment: inside **didSelectRowAt** deselect the cell

Comment: @Sh_Khan please could you elaborate?  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: To be clear, this is NOT a bug. UIKit is not thread-safe. If you try to display a new view controller from a background thread, bad things will happen. The most common result is long delays, as the OP describes, but other results, including crashes, are possible. If wrapping the present call in a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` fixes it, you were trying to display your view controller from a background thread.

Comment: top of select function do **tableView.deselectRow(at:indexPath, 
        animated:false)** also do you have any web call inside that function before dismiss ??